# React Native and Swift Integration: Not Receiving Delegate Callbacks in Custom Module

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, callback

`I'm working on integrating a custom Swift module with my React Native app. The module is supposed to handle ID card classification using the IdCardClassification class and communicate the results back to React Native through delegate methods. However, I'm not receiving any results in the delegate callbacks IdCardClassification(didReceive:) and IdCardClassification(didFailWithError:). Below is the implementation of my Swift class CustomModule which conforms to the IdCardClassificationDelegate protocol.

`
import Foundation
import React
import SDK

```
@objc(CustomModule)
class CustomModule: NSObject, IdCardClassificationDelegate {
  
  @objc
  static func requiresMainQueueSetup() -> Bool {
    return true
  }
  
  var successCallback: RCTResponseSenderBlock?
  var errorCallback: RCTResponseSenderBlock?
  
  @objc
  func presentIdCardClassification(_ url: String, token: String, successCallback: @escaping RCTResponseSenderBlock, errorCallback: @escaping RCTResponseSenderBlock) {
    self.successCallback = successCallback
    self.errorCallback = errorCallback
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      if let topViewController = UIViewController.topMostViewController() {
        print(topViewController)
        SDK.shared.presentIdCardClassificationCiewController(
          viewController: topViewController,
          url: url,
          token: token
        )
      } else {
        self.errorCallback?("Error")
      }
    }
  }
  
  func IdCardClassification(didReceive result: Any) {
    successCallback?([result])
  }
  
  func IdCardClassification(didFailWithError error: Error) {
    errorCallback?([error.localizedDescription])
  }
}


extension UIViewController {
  @objc static func topMostViewController() -> UIViewController? {
    if let rootController = UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow })?.rootViewController {
      var topController = rootController
      while let presentedViewController = topController.presentedViewController {
        topController = presentedViewController
      }
      return topController
    }
    return nil
  }
}
```

`

`
// CustomModule.m

#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(CustomModule, NSObject)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(presentIdCardClassification:(NSString *)url token:(NSString *)token successCallback:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)successCallback errorCallback:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)errorCallback)

@end
`

I ensure that the delegate is set up correctly, and the class is presented properly from the top-most view controller. Despite this, the delegate methods do not seem to be triggered. I'm looking for suggestions on what might be going wrong and how to fix it.`